# Sample code to show the use of 'FROM' in hyperledger composer query language

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

How to use 'FROM' in hyperledger composer query language....sample code
[hyperledger query language](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/query-language)..

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is correct about FROM, but it has no practical use at the moment it is a placeholder for future features.  So there are no examples of its use.

(If you see any tutorial examples on the Web for Hstorian Queries using FROM, it is likely that they will now not work and will need to have the FROM rule removed.)